# Some explanation about 8 queen solution that use permutation

Tags: prolog, n-queens

I am studyin Prolog for an universitary exam on SWI Prolog implementation.

I have some doubt about how work this version of 8 Queen problem that solve the problem using the permutations:

```
solution(Queens) :-
 permutation([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], Queens),
 safe(Queens).

permutation([],[]).

permutation([Head|Tail],PermList) :-
 permutation(Tail,PermTail),
 del(Head,PermList,PermTail).

del(Item,[Item|List],List).

del(Item,[First|List],[First|List1]) :-
 del(Item,List,List1).

safe([]).

safe([Queen|Others]) :-
 safe(Others),
 noattack(Queen,Others,1).

noattack(_,[],_).

noattack(Y,[Y1|Ylist],Xdist) :-
 Y1-Y=\=Xdist,
 Y-Y1=\=Xdist,
 Dist1 is Xdist + 1,
 noattack(Y,Ylist,Dist1).
```

In a previous resolution I used this solution template: [1\Y1, 2\Y2, 3\Y3, 4\Y4, 5\Y5, 6\Y6, 7\Y7, 8\Y8] that simply say that every queen have to be on different rows the X calue could be constrained.

This version of the program it's pretty difference because we can observe that to prevent vertical attack all the queens have to be on different rows, so I have a queen for each row.

So without losing information so I can say that the solution will be a permutation of the list: **[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]** in wich every element rappresent the Y coordinate of a queen.

so in this case I am rappresenting a queen position only by its Y coordinate (its row index)

So I have the **solution** relation than say that a list **Queens** is a solution if  Queens is a premutation of **[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]** original list and if this permutation is **safe** (every queen in this permutation list don't attack the others queen).

Ok, this is clear...now it is defined the **safe** relation.

There is a base case that say that if the list is empty then this is safe because there is no attack.

And there is a general case in wich the list is not empty. If the list is not empty I can divide it in **[Queen|Others]** where **Queen** is the **first queen in the list** and **Others** is the remaining sublist...so the original list **[Queen|Others]** is safe if the sublist Others it is itself a solution (if it is safe, if there is no attack in Others) and if the first item **Queen** do not attack the other queen in others sublist...

Ok...until now I think that it is clear for me...

Now I have some problems with the definition of **noattack** relation !!!

The problem is that I rappresent a queen position only by its Y coordinate and the X coordinate it is
not explicity present.

I have understand that for circumvent this limitation of the rappresentation there is the folowing generalizzation (I hope to have understood well...I am not so sure...): ** I know also that there must be a queen on each column of the board, so the X distance from the first queen in the list (Queen) and the sublist Others must be 1**

Where the distance from the first item Queen and the sublist Others is the X distance from the first item Queen and the queen nearest to it, is it righ my reasoning?

So the **noattack** relation is TRUE if the queen are on different columns (always true for construction) and I can express that have to be on different row sayng that the X distance from Queen and the nearest queen in the Others sublist is 1.

But, if my reasoning is truem I am finding many trouble trying to understand how rappresent this thing in this part of code:

```
noattack(Y,[Y1|Ylist],Xdist) :-
 Y1-Y=\=Xdist,
 Y-Y1=\=Xdist,
 Dist1 is Xdist + 1,
 noattack(Y,Ylist,Dist1).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think your problem is only these 2 lines:

```
Y-Y1=/=Xdist,
Y1-Y=/=Xdist,
```

it checks whether the queen which has Y, attacks the queen in the row with a distance of Xdist in a diagonal way or not. (`|Y - Y1| = Xdist --> diagonal attack` ).

the other way to attack other queens is to qttack them in the same row, that doesn't happen simply because the solution is a permutation of `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`. so something like `[1,1,3,4,5,6,7,8]` never happens and thats enough to check diagonals.

I hope it solved the problem.

p.s. note that `Y1` is the Y coordinate of the head of the `Others` from the rule `Safe/1`. so it is a queen with a `Xdist` of 1 at first, then it backtracks to other rows.

### clarification

we are talking about `noattack/3`. you give it three arguments:

**first**: `Y` *coordinate of current queen*,

**second**: *a right-most list* `[Y1| Ylist]` *the begins somewhere after where* `Y` *is in the list, and continues to the end of the primary list.(yes this is a sublist of the solution)*, and

**third**: `Xdist` *is the index-distance between current queen (which has Y) and the queen which is gonna be checked with the current queen (which has Y1 and is the head of second argument).*

third argument is necessary because without it we can not check diagonal interaction between the current queen and and the queen which has Y1. it is really basic mathematics, you have 2 points in the coordinate system with only natural numbers. lets say these 2 points attack each other in a diagonal way if and only-if **abs(x1 - x2) = abs(y1 - y2)**.

Example #1    . and if you understood my explanations well, check it as Accepted.

**P1 = (3, 4) and P2 = (1, 2)** `-->` these points have a diagonal attack because **abs(3-1) = abs(4-2) = 2**

Example #2

**P1 = (3, 4) and P2 = (7, 0)** `-->` these points have a diagonal attack because **abs(3-7) = abs(4-0) = 4**

this is why we check both  `Y1-Y =\= Xdist`  and  `Y-Y1 =\= Xdist` . because whenever there is a diagonal attack at least one of them is gonna be `true`. when non of them was true, it means that there is no diagonal attack between the queen with `Y` and the queen with `Y1`. so we can proceed to checking the next queen which is the head of `Ylist`.

I hope that's enough. this is a very easy problem, Just read it carefully and if you couldn't understand again try to trace the algorithm on a piece of paper yourself. that's a way always works.

Comment: are you saying me that this check controll if there is no diagonal attack (I can't have vertical or horizzontal attack for the solution construction). Y1 is the Y coordinate of the head of the Others sublist that came from Safe/1 rule. Y is the current queen. The Xdist value 1 (from the rule safe\1).
So if Y-Y1=/=1, Y1-Y=/=1, it is true means that Y and Y1 are not on the same diagonal...I am not so sure that I have understood...is it right?

Comment: i don't understand this part of you sentence: So if Y-Y1=/=1, Y1-Y=/=1, it is true means that Y and Y1 are not on the same diagonal. in general if delta_Y = delta_X it means that there is diagonal interaction between points.

Comment: @AndreaNobili I renew my answer and try to make it more clear.

Comment: @AndreaNobili read my clarifications. if you understood don't hesitate to vote-up and accept the answer. thx.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same confusion when solving the same problem in recursion using C. There are two possible directions for diagonal attacks. Number each square with x,y coordinates with top-left being 0,0. You will then see that these two attacking diagonal detection or calculation satisfies the conditions:

- x1 - y1 == x2 - y2
- x1 + y1 == x2 + y2

I annotated the comparison above in C equality notation and not Prolog notation. Between two points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2), there is queen diagonal attack if one of conditions above is meet.